# Using or in a conditional statement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement

I have a conditional statement in Page_Load that checks if the value of a text box is blank. however, I also want to test for null as well. I'm having some issue with my syntax.

This is my conditional statement (works well):

```
 If (textUserName.Text.ToString <> "")  Then
        textUserName.[ReadOnly] = True
      End If
```

My question is, how can I check for null as well using "or" (preferred)?
...perhaps using elseif

This is what I've tried using "elseif":

```
If (textUserName.Text.ToString <> "") Then
            textUserName.[ReadOnly] = True
        ElseIf (textUserName.Text.ToString <> vbNull) Then
            textUserName.[ReadOnly] = True
        End If
```

Though my application functions well w/ the condition I'm using, plus the field for the username is set in the database to not allow Nulls, I was just curious as to how I would set my condition if I had to deal with a Null value. Thanks

Comment: It's always helpful to tag the language you're using. Many ASP.NET developers are familiar with C#. I've tagged it as VB.NET for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` to check for null strings

```
If textUserName.Text <> "" Or Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(textUserName.Text) Then
   textUserName.[ReadOnly] = True
End If
```

Or... Which I believe is better:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Trim(textUserName.Text)) Then
   textUserName.[ReadOnly] = True
End If
```

Comment: The logical 'OrElse' should be used instead of the bitwise 'Or'.